Can the forms dominated by a maximum of semi-norms be described?
Suppose that $E$ is a Banach space and $p, q: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ are continuous semi-norms.
Let $K_p, K_q \subset E^*$ be the sets
$K_p = \{f \in E^* \ | \ |f(x)| \leq p(x) \; \text{for all} \; x \in E\}$ and $K_q = \{f \in E^* \ | \ |f(x)| \leq q(x) \; \text{for all} \; x \in E\}.$
Can $K_{\max(p,q)} = \{|f| \leq \max(p,q)\}$ be described in terms of $K_p$ and $K_q$?
If $f\in K_p$, then $|f| \leq p \leq \max(p,q)$, hence
$\text{conv}(K_p \cup K_q) \subset K_{\max(p,q)}$.
Is equality guaranteed without further hypothesis about $E$, $p$ or $q$?

Yes. Consider $E \oplus E$ equipped with the seminorm $s(x, y) = \max\{p(x), q(y)\}$. Let $\pi: E \to E \oplus E$ be the diagonal inclusion $\pi(x) = (x, x)$. Then $s \circ \pi = \max\{p, q\}$. Thus, any $f \in K_{\max\{p, q\}}$ can be understood as a linear functional on $\pi(E)$ bounded above by $s|_{\pi(E)}$, so by Hahn-Banach, there exists an extension $g: E \oplus E \to \mathbb{K}$ s.t. $|g| \leq s$.
For notational purposes, for any seminorm $p$ on some space $V$, we shall denote its dual norm by $p’$, i.e., for a linear functional $f: V \to \mathbb{K}$,
$$p’(f) = \inf\{C \geq 0: |f(x)| \leq Cp(x), \forall x \in V\}$$
Now, any linear functional $g$ on $E \oplus E$ can clearly be decomposed as $g_1 \oplus g_2$ for linear functionals $g_1, g_2$ on $E$. It is not hard to check,
$$s’(g) = p’(g_1) + q’(g_2)$$
As $s’(g) \leq 1$, we have $p’(g_1) + q’(g_2) \leq 1$. From there, it is not hard to check that $f = g \circ \pi = g_1 + g_2$ is in $\text{conv}(K_p \cup K_q)$ - it is a convex combination of some rescalings of $g_1$ and $g_2$, which are in $K_p$ and $K_q$, respectively.

Alternatively, one can use the theorem of bipolars which would give the weak$^$-closure of the convex hull. By Alaoglu's theorem, $K_p$ and $K_q$ are weak$^$-compact and hence so is conv$(K_p\cup K_q)$. In particular, it is weak$^*$-closed.
